# RayTracer project in C#

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, raytracing

When I was at university, I took a subject in raytracing (graphics synthesis) and we got a chance to write a 3D ray tracer in C++. That was heaps of fun, except I long ago lost my code in the great hard drive crash of '04'....many files were lost...

Is there a RayTracer I can play with in C# that isn't written in one line? Something that's written with proper object orientation so I can extend it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Heh, I also had great fun writing a ray tracer in c++ for a university course - and all the data was also lost in a hard disk crash in '04.  Fortunately, I had a backup of the actual code  *whew*
Damn you, IBM DeathStar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User Andalmeida over at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=3589667) has some nice articles on raytracing in C# which seems to fit the bill.